# the sequence of the OR operator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following OR operator, now currently if the c is null the Error view will be returned and no null exception will be raised on the second check (!c.ManagedBy...); but this will only happen if the compiler perform the (c==null) check before the (!c.Ismanaged..) check.

```
Book c = elearningrepository.GetBook(id);

if ((c == null) || (!c.IsManagedBy(User.Identity.Name)))
{
    return View("Error");
}
```

so can I guarantee that the compiler will always perform the c==null check first or it is better to split the above check into two separate If statements to explicitly enforce the sequence.
BR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`||` does short-circuit and will evaluate exactly as you have described. There's no need to separate the statements.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346(v=vs.100).aspx):

> The conditional-OR operator (||) performs a logical-OR of its bool
>   operands. If the first operand evaluates to true, the second operand
>   isn't evaluated. If the first operand evaluates to false, the second
>   operator determines whether the OR expression as a whole evaluates to
>   true or false.

*Edited for the most recent MSDN article (2010).*

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can rely on the behaviour that the left operand of `||` will be evaluated first, and that the right operand won't be evaluated if the left operand evaluates to true.

This is guaranteed in section 7.12 of the C# 4 spec:

> - The operation `x || y` corresponds to the operation `x | y`, except that `y` is evaluated only if `x` is not true.

Answer (score 2):

> so can i guarantee that the compiler will always perform the c==null
>   check first

Yes this is guaranteed, the `||` operator will short circuit after the first condition that evaluates to `true` (evaluation order is from left to right).

Answer (score 1):

I'd separate it only for the sake of being more clear.

Comment: Keeping them separate can lead to unnecessary nesting. It's certainly a matter of choice but there's no reason to make them separate conditionals.

Comment: @yuck this if statement is fairly simple but when dealing with more complex statement i always prefer "wasting" some chars/lines in order to have a clearer view of the statement.

Comment: @Hezi: I agree with Yuck.  Separating this case would require two returns for `View("Error")` and not only "wastes" chars/lines and computation time, but also other developer's time when supporting this code in the future having to read through the cases separately when it's not required

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will always evaluate the left expression first. If it evaluates to `true`, the right one will be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `||` operator guarantees that the first operand is evaluated first, and the second operand is only evaluated if the first is false.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `||` resolves left-to-right, meaning that the left operand will be evaluated first, then the right. It also short-circuits, so no worry of the right operand being evaluated when the left operand is `true`. Finally, it also has a lower precedence than `==` or `!`, so you can even drop the parentheses and it's still completely safe and will never fail you  :)

```
if (c == null || !c.IsManagedBy(User.Identity.Name))
{
    return View("Error");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C# guarantees it is a left to right order of execution. The || as opposed to | has short circuit evaluation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx